# F$0.9999.....≈1$ or $0.9999.....=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

What is the intuition behind the fact that:

$$ 0.9999999\ldots = 1 $$

**My Teacher's Proof:**

We know that any number which belongs to the interval $[0,1)$ can be uniquely written as decimal expansion:

$$ x=0.a_1a_2a_3 \ldots = a_1×10^-1+a_2×10^-2+a_3×10^-3 + \ldots $$

where the digits $a_1,a_2,a_3 \ldots$ satisfy the following:

Each digit $a_i$ is an integer in the 10-element set ${0,1,2,....,9}$

So, $$ 0.9999999 \ldots = \frac{9}{10} + \frac{9}{100} + \frac{9}{1000} \ldots = 9 [$\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{1000} \ldots$)] = 9 × \frac{1}{9} = 1 $$

**My doubt:**

Since

$$ [\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{1000} \ldots)] ≈ \frac{1}{9} $$

So $0.9999999 \ldots ≈ 1$ not exactly equal to $1$.

Am I correct?

Suppose some people jump towards the right with velocity $u$ relative to a cart. Let the mass of each person be $m$ and that of cart be $M$. If there are $N$ people then, $Nm=M$

**Case 2**: All people jump simultaneously.

$$ \Rightarrow Nm(u-v_B)=M(v_B) $$

Hence, $v_B=\frac{u}{2}$

**Case 1**: People jump one after other.

After the first man jumps off the velocity $v_1$, acquired by the cart to the left,

$$ m(u-v_1)=(M+Nm-m)v_1 $$

Hence, $v_1 = \frac{mu}{M+Nm}$

After the second person jumps off, the velocity $v_2$ acquired by cart to the left,

$$ m(u-v_2)+(M+Nm-m)v_1=(M+Nm-2m)v_2 $$

Hence, $v_2=v_1+\frac{mu}{M+Nm-m}$

Similarly, after the $n^{th}$ person jumps off, the velocity $v_n$ acquired by the cart to the left $(2≤n≤N)$.

So, $v_n=v_{n-1}+\frac{mu}{M+Nm-nm}$

Therefore the velocity $(v_A)$ after all people have jumped off,

$$ v_A=\frac{mu}{M+Nm}+\frac{mu}{M+(N-1)m}+\cdots+\frac{mu}{M+m} $$

How do I proceed from here?

Answer:

> $$\frac{v_A}{v_B}=2ln2 $$

Comment: "We know that any number [...] can be uniquely written as" That's an assumption. Under that assumption $0.999\ldots\neq1$, clearly. The question is, do we really know this?

Comment: ^THAT is probably the better dupe.

Comment: $1/9=.1111...$ It's not approximate.

Comment: One intuition for why $0.999\ldots =1$ could be the following: ask yourself what else it could possibly be! You might think that it is less than $1$, but if so, how much less is it? No matter how tiny an amount less than $1$ you claim it to be (e.g. $0.00000001$), you should be able to intuitively see that $0.999\ldots$ will actually end up getting *closer* to $1$ than by this (once you've gone past enough of the $9$'s). So $0.999\ldots$ can't actually be less than $1$.

Comment: 0.999.... as defined by the question IS NOT A NUMBER.  The question defines a procedure of adding many 9s to the end of a number which doesn't mean it must be a number. What we are talking of about is the LIMIT of the sequence 0.9, 0.99, 0999..., etc, Any 'proof' that doesn't address this issue is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> We know that any number which belongs to the interval $[0,1)$ can be uniquely written as decimal expansion <sub><sup>[...]</sup></sub>

This is not true. For instance, $\frac12$ can be written as $0.5$ or $0.4999\ldots$

And $0.999\ldots$ is *exactly* equal to $1$. If they were different, then their difference $1-0.999\ldots$ would be non-zero; but clearly $1-0.999\ldots = 0.000\ldots = 0$.

Comment: And why is $1-0.99999... = 0$? In my opinion you "prove" the claim by saying that it's true.

Comment: @amsmath: because if any decimal digit were non-zero, it would lead to an immediate contradiction.